# LWUIT Scrolling

Tags: java-me, lwuit

Here is another question regarding JavaMe and LWUIT.

I need to manually scroll `TextArea` with help of methods or etc. `TextArea` contains methods responsible only for obtaining current position of scrolling and its enable and disable.

How can I do this?

---

I solved problem by using inheritance from `TextArea` and delegation protected methods of scrolling (setScrollX and setScrollY accordingly). Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextArea extends TextField. In the TextField class there is the `setCursorPosition` method. So my suggestion is to use this method and you loop through the TextArea content until a certain position you desire is reached.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scrollRectToVisible() which is often more convenient than scrollY and adds smooth scrolling animation.