# In LWUIT, How to programmatically set "TextArea's Scroll" back to its top, after moving it down?

Tags: java-me, scroll, scrollbar, lwuit, lwuit-textarea

Using LWUIT, I have a `Form` with two components: a read-only `TextArea` and a `Button`:

```
TextArea text = new TextArea("blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah ...");
text.setEditable(false);
form.addComponent(text);

Button button = new Button("Press Me !");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          // DESIRED CODE IS HERE ...
     }
});
form.addComponent(button);
```

The `TextArea` has a `Scrollbar` because it contains a long `String`, when the user moves `DOWN` the `TextArea`'s `Scrollbar` moves down until it reaches the end of the `String`, then the `Button` get focused leaving the `TextArea`'s `Scrollbar` at the end of the `TextArea`. 
I want that, when the `Button` is clicked, the scrollbar returns back to its original state in the `Top` of the `TextArea` instead of being in the `Bottom` of the `TextArea`. **How could I do this ?**

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484720/lwuit-scrolling

Comment: That solves the issue, thanks ! I'll post the answer for anyone who has the same problem, to have it published for later searches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution for those who are interested. 
by using a custom TextArea

```
public class CustomTextArea extends TextArea {
    public TextAreaScrollControlled(String text) {
        super(text);
    }

    public void resetScrollBackToTop() {
        setScrollY(0);
    }
}
```

Then the code is the following (instead of the one posted in the question):

```
CustomTextArea text = new CustomTextArea("blah blah blah blah blah blah ...");
text.setEditable(false);
addComponent(text);

Button button = new Button("Press Me !");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          text.resetScrollBackToTop(); // SOLUTION
     }
});
form.addComponent(button);
```

PS. "text" should be final or a member of the class ;)

Comment: Great! I will try to do that!

Comment: scrollRectToVisible(0, 0, 10, 10) should also work and it public as far as I recall